# How to install mysqlclient python package?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I now learn `django`. On database learn `mysql`. But dont install `mysqlclient`. Initially get `Microsoft C++ 14.0 or greater than required` error. I solve this. I install build tools. But now get another error:

```
running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\MySQLdb
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL     
/DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,1,1,'final',0) -D__version__=2.1.1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include\mariadb"    
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include" -IC:\Users\Feruz\.virtualenvs\storefront-GD3EPR4W\include
-Ic:\users\feruz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\feruz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include       
"-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files     
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program     
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt"        
/TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
      _mysql.c
      MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: mysql.h: No such file or directory,
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' 
failed with exit code 2


  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> mysqlclient

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
[0m
Installation Failed
```

How to solve this? Please help me. I use windows

Comment: *mysql.h: No such file or directory,* do you have installed the developer files from mysql?

Comment: You can try to install the MySQL Connector C library, which includes the mysql.h file, and then update the include path to point to the location of the library.

Comment: I install MySQL Connector C library

Comment: @onetwo12 please write what need I do

Comment: Try this: `pip install wheel` 
`pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`